# How does Context-registered receivers work

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver

My confusion is that -

If a **Context-registered receiver** receives broadcasts as long as their registering context is valid- then how does an app get notified if it's not launched.

In **Manifest-declared receivers** the receiver app would have got started by the system, so how does it work for **Context-registered receiver** ?

Comment: "...how does an app get notified if it's not launched." - It doesn't.

Comment: if it doesn't get started or launched then how will it receive implicit broadcasts if it's not launched already?

Comment: Prior to Oreo, apps could register Receivers in the manifest for implicit broadcasts. As of Oreo, for apps targeting API 26+, that will no longer work (unless the broadcast is [one of the exceptions](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions.html)), so an app just won't get any non-exempt implicit broadcasts unless it's alive, and has a Receiver appropriately registered.

Answer (score 1):

One way or another, you need `context` to receive [`Broadcasts`](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html) in [`onReceive`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#onReceive(android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent)) method of [`BroadcastReceiver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)

For **Manifest-registered** receivers, if application is not running then system **may** start the app and deliver the broadcast if the app is not currently running. After `onReceive()`, the system can kill the process at any time to reclaim memory. The passed `context` in this case is:
Context class: `android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext`
Application context: `android.app.Application`

For **Context-registered** receivers, it is clearly stated in [Broadcasts | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html):

> Context-registered receivers receive broadcasts as long as their registering context is valid. For an example, if you register within an Activity context, you receive broadcasts as long as the activity is not destroyed. If you register with the Application context, you receive broadcasts as long as the app is running.

Comment: This is basically repeating what the OP already said in the question.

Comment: Nice to get clarification that application context can be used to register broadcast receivers. I need to use it for api 23 legacy connection manager implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare a `BroadcastReceiver` in the manifest, Android will **create an instance** of that `BroadcastReceiver` and call `onReceive()` when it wants to dispatch a broadcast `Intent` to that receiver (based on the specified `<intent-filter>` conditions.